# A cada rodada loop var troca

Tags: bash, shell-script

Estou desenvolvendo um sisteminha em shell que tem um formulario para adicionar alguns campos.

Quantidade Produto ValorUnitario etc...

Preciso que a cada volta que o loop da ele troque uma váriavel, para assim eu chamar ele no formulario!

No caso é os prev, a cada rodada ele troca para prev1, no outro prevdois troca para prevdois1, ai na outra rodada, prev2, prevdois2 e assim por diante, isto porque eu vou chamar estas váriaveis para salvar em um formulario. alguma ajuda?

```
while [ "$sair" != "sair" ]; do
i=$((i+1))
for filter in Produto Quantidade Descricao PrecoUnitario PrecoTotal; do
    read -p "${filter}: " ${filter}$i


**prev=$Produto
prevdois=$Quantidade**
done
    read -p "Deseja sair? [sair] ou enter para continuar: " sair
done
```

Comment: Você quer adicionar na frente 1, 2, 3 .... da string do prev?

Comment: ISSO! pode ser! é que eu preciso chamar estas variaveis diferentes em cada round para um formulario!
No caso vamos dizer que na primeira passada o prev vale abacate
prev=abacate na segunda prev ele vale abacaxi 2prev=abacaxi
E assim por diante!

Comment: Eu nunca vi essa sintaxe de colocar asteriscos `*` antes do nome da variável

Comment: Isso pq eu botei negrito aqui no site kkkkk, descartar!
Não consegui me expressar direito!
Eu preciso que a cada loop a variavel troque e fique fixa!
Para eu conseguir chamar no formulario... já que são produtos diferentes.
Sacaram? a saida vai ser em um arquivo HTML, problema que a saida como é de se esperar é sempre a ultima rodada. e eu precisava que ficasse independente...
Exemplo:

   <tr>
      <td>$prev</td>
      <td>$prevdois</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>$prev</td>
      <td>$prevdois</td>
   </tr>

Answer (score 0):

Use *eval* com o seu contador *i*:

```
eval prev$i=$Produto
eval prevdois$i=$Quantidade
```

Quando *i = 1*, o resultado acima será:

```
prev1=$Produto
prevdois1=$Quantidade
```

No entanto, ainda que possível fazer dessa forma, sugiro que dê uma olhada em arrays para executar esta tarefa.